# Signature verification failed when accessing travelocity.com / saml2-web-app-pickup-dispatch.com apps with SAML2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have wso2is v5.10.0 and when I created a service provider with the travelocity.com app, I found an error when accessing the application

[image]

Error log :

[image]

Config Service Provider :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a signature validation error.

**Workaround1**

You can either remove the signature validation option in the Application configuration.
[image]
**Workaround2:**

Replace the Keystore in the travelocity sample app(`<TOMCAT_HOME>/WEB-INF/classes/wso2carbon.jks`) with the keystore of the WSO2 Identity Server `<is-home>/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks`

**Solution:**

To fix it properly,  you have to add the public key of the identity server (`<is-home>/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks`) to the keystore in the saml2-web-app-pickup-dispatch.com app (`<TOMCAT_HOME>/WEB-INF/classes/wso2carbon.jks`)

1. Export the public certificate of IS from
   `<IS_HOME>/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks`
2. You can export the cert using key tool command
3. The default certificate alias is wso2carbon and the key store password is wso2carbon.
4. Then import the exported certificate to `<TOMCAT_HOME>/WEB-INF/classes/wso2carbon.jks` .
5. Finally update the IdPPublicCertAlias parameter in `<TOMCAT_HOME>/WEB-INF/classes/sso.properties` file with newly imported certificate alias