# Error when trying out sample saml application

Tags: wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

I have setted up salml2-pickup-dispatch.com sample application and when I trying to login to the application I got below errors.

`WARN {org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature} - Signature verification failed.`

`WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.validators.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestValidator} - Signature validation for Authentication Request failed for the request of Issuer :saml2-web-app-pickup-dispatch.com in tenantDomain:carbon.super`

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to Signature verification issue.

You can quickly fix this issue by replacing the Keystore in the salml2-pickup-dispatch sample app(<saml2-pickup-dispatch_home>/WEB-INF/classes/wso2carbon.jks) with the keystore of the WSO2 Identity Server (/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks).

You can refer to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61093340/9514885 for more details